# suppose a(x)f(x) + b(x)g(x) = 1, where a(x),f(x),g(x) and b(x) are polynomials. Prove that f(x) and g(x) have no common roots

Tags: polynomials

I've tried everything that I know, and I can't seem to figure this question out? Any sort of help would be good.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ and $g$ share a root, say $x_0$, then $a(x_0)f(x_0)+b(x_0)g(x_0)=0\neq1$, contradictory to the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

If f(x) and g(x) both have a common root then the value of the equation for that root would be 0 which is a contradiction to the given equation.